# Using an old laptop as a SQL server to store online game data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on various game projects for the last year and would like to now get into some basic multiplayer connectivity.

I figured web-based games would work best for me as I work as a junior web developer and have experience with SQL and how to grab data from a SQL server and use it in a web page.

My question is how I host the SQL data: I have an old laptop kicking around and thought I could leave it running in my room as a basic SQL server, but is there more to it than that?

I can happily just install SQL Express on my laptop but does that then set up a location on my laptop that stores data? Or do I need to be looking for a small dedicated server unit?

I feel like I'm asking a question I should know the answer to but I guess it is down to a hole in my knowledge as to how SQL databases are stored etc.

So in conclusion, can i host a SQL server on my laptop? And is it achieved by simply installing SQL Express 2014 and creating a database and table set?

Worth also noting that the game will be small scale so I'm not looking for a rock solid solution with potential to scale up, just something to start off with.

Regards, Josh

Comment: will you host the webpage also on your old laptop?

Comment: @WongKongPhooey: SQL Express might be the way to go considering the licensing costs of an SQL server. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx#fbid=2p0hOEUTXiz

Comment: good question, i would host the webpage itself on my GoDaddy hosting package I currently have, open to changing this however if it complicates things

Comment: @bic Thanks for this, a free solution is just what I am looking for :), I'll use SQL Express instead, (question updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whilst it would work, you would be better served getting it hosted on windows Azure, there are a number of free hostings availible for databases, the logistics of hosting at home become a little too much after a short period of time.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/aspnet/

Comment: Windows Azure is just the kind of free option I was looking for and would clearly save me a lot of setup time, a good suggestion, straight answer, happy to mark this as my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Install SQL Express
- Create a database and table using SQL Management Studio (Logging on to your local SQL express instance)
- Set up port forwarding on your router, to forward incoming SQL traffic to the laptop.
- Set up Dynamic DNS on your router. If your router does not support his, get a dyamic DNS update client and run it on the laptop.
- Use the dynamic DNS and port that your forwarded, in your connection string to access it from "internet" hosted web page.
- I recommend changing the incmoing port your are forwarding, to "hide" the SQL instance from the obvious port. I.e. Port In - > 7546 forwarded to laptop ip, on port 1433

You may need to do a bit of research on each point.. but it will really benefit you in learning about the above... I consider it crucial knowledge for a good developer to know what is happening "behind" the scenes...

Comment: thanks for this really detailed response, i agree that i should aim as a developer to learn this kind of stuff, and this answer has only encouraged that